# Proof of Binet-Cauchy identity through the polarization transformation

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

In Steele's "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class" exercise 3.7 asks to prove the Cauchy-Binet identity:
$$<a,s><b,t>-<a,t><s,b>=\sum_{j<k}\begin{vmatrix}a_j & b_j\\ a_k & b_k\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}s_j & t_j\\ s_k & t_k\end{vmatrix},$$
where $<,>$ is the scalar product, starting from Lagrange identity:
$$<a,a><b,b>-<a,b>^2=\sum_{j<k}\begin{vmatrix}a_j & b_j\\ a_k & b_k\end{vmatrix}^2.$$

The author suggests to use to this purpose the *polarization transformation*
$$T(f(u),v)=\frac{f(u+v)-f(u-v)}{4},$$
saying that it is useful to transform squares in products.

In the sketch of the solution then he says that if we fix $b$ and polarize $a$ with $s$, we obtain
$$<a,s><b,b>-<a,b><s,b>=\sum_{j<k}\begin{vmatrix}a_j & b_j\\ a_k & b_k\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}s_j & b_j\\ s_k & b_k\end{vmatrix},$$
and then if we fix $a$ and $s$ and polarize $b$ with $t$ he says that we obtain the Cauchy-Binet identity.

Here it is my attempt that does not arrive to the wished identity.

I start observing that $T(f(u),v)$ is linear in $f()$, i.e. $T(\alpha_1 f_1(u)+\alpha_2 f_2(u),v)=\alpha_1 T(f_1(u),v)+ \alpha_2 T(f_2(u),v)$.
Then, I observe that if $f(u)=g(u,u)$, where $g(x,y)$ is bilinear in $x$ and $y$, it holds:
$$T(f(u),v)=\frac{g(u,v)+g(u,v)}{2},$$
and if $g()$ is also symmetric ($g(x,y)=g(y,x)$) it holds
$$T(f(u),v)=g(u,v).$$

If $b$ is considered as a constant, Lagrange identity can be read as $h_1(a)+h_2(a)=h_3(a)$, where $h_i(a)=g_i(a,a)$ with $g_i(x,y)$ symmetric and bilinear. Applying $T(,s)$ to both sides we obtain indeed:
$$<a,s><b,b>-<a,b><s,b>=\sum_{j<k}\begin{vmatrix}a_j & b_j\\ a_k & b_k\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}s_j & b_j\\ s_k & b_k\end{vmatrix},$$

My difficulty is now with the second transformation, because only the first term on the LHS can be expressed as a symmetric and bilinear function $\tilde g_1(x,y)=<a,s><x,y>$ that is symmetric and bilinear, but the other terms can be expressed as just  bilinear functions, leading then to a (correct) but different equality:
$$<a,s><b,t>-\frac{<a,b><s,t>+<a,t><s,b>}{2}=\sum_{j<k}\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{vmatrix}a_j & b_j\\ a_k & b_k\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}s_j & t_j\\ s_k & t_k\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}a_j & t_j\\ a_k & t_k\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}s_j & b_j\\ s_k & b_k\end{vmatrix}\right).$$

Any help to understand how Steele was expecting the reader  to use the polarization transformation is welcome.

Comment: My guess is that this is a mistake. It seems very plausible that the second polarization will give the required identity, but as you've shown, this isn't the case. It's a shame it doesn't work: even the $3$-dimensional case is of interest, since it would give a short proof by polarizing $|| a \wedge b||^2 = ||a||^2 ||b^2|| - (a\cdot b)^2$ of the cross product identity $(a \wedge b) \cdot (s \wedge t) = (a \cdot b)(s\cdot t)-(a\cdot t)(b\cdot s)$.

Comment: MO copy of this question: [Proof of Binet-Cauchy identity through the polarization transformation](https://mathoverflow.net/q/221370)